Sql where condition on an alias column
I have a user list api - where I am trying to add filters/sorting via various conditions.
In this example here - I am calculating a distance value from the logged in users lat/lng - against the other users in the system.
    SELECT u.*, (
      6371 * acos (
        cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat')))) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lng'))) - radians(?)) +
        sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat'))))
      )
    ) AS dist
    FROM users_tbl u

I want to add a WHERE condition which is something like this
dist <= '6'

however - when I try and add this to the query - it breaks -- I am unsure if I should handle the where condition as dist, or u.dist - I don't know how to get this working.
    SELECT u.*, (
      6371 * acos (
        cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat')))) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lng'))) - radians(?)) +
        sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat'))))
      )
    ) AS dist
    FROM users_tbl u
    WHERE dist <= '6'

is it a casting issue where dist is a number or a string etc..

What do you mean by "it breaks"?

In a WHERE clause sql server doesn't yet understand the name you gave your expression in the SELECT, so it must be repeated as an expression:
SELECT u.*, (
      6371 * acos (
        cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat')))) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lng'))) - radians(?)) +
        sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat'))))
      )
    ) AS dist
    FROM users_tbl u
    WHERE (
      6371 * acos (
        cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat')))) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lng'))) - radians(?)) +
        sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat'))))
      )
    ) <= '6'

This is a little verbose and ugly, so it may be more palatable this way, using a CTE:
; with cte as (
    SELECT u.*, (
          6371 * acos (
            cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat')))) * cos(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lng'))) - radians(?)) +
            sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.locality, '$.lat'))))
          )
        ) AS dist
        FROM users_tbl u
)
select * from cte 
where cte.dist <= '6'

For a little extra color, it is useful to realize that in terms of writing a query a SELECT clause is first, but when the query is executed internally, the SELECT is actually quite late in the order of operations, and therefore you can think (with a little imagination and much blurring of technical details) that the WHERE clause doesn't know about the SELECT clause yet.

Thank you for that - how would you handle different expressions like distance calc - and age calc inside the same query like that? stack multiple cte's?

I think you could probably add more expressions inside the one cte, and then refer to these by name when you do a select on the cte, just as you did with dist.
